# How to execute command using spawnSync passing environment varible?

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I am trying to execute below command using spawnSync in nodejs. But I am not able to execute it.
Command to execute:

```
grep -w 'SYSTEM_SEC_LANG'  ${ENV_VAR_NAME}/scripts/i18n/lang.sh | head -n 1 | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

I am able to execute this command in Linux terminal. But when I am trying to execute the same command using spawnSync nodjs utility. It is not working.

The way I am executing it:

```
const output = spawnSync("grep",["-w", "SYSTEM_SEC_LANG", `${ENV_VAR_NAME}/scripts/i18n/lang.sh`, "|", "head","-n", "1", "|", "awk", "-F", '=', '{print $2}', "|", "awk", '{print $1}'], { encoding: 'utf-8', shell: false });
```

Error:

```
output: [
    null,
    '',
    'grep: `${ENV_VAR_NAME}/scripts/i18n/lang.sh`: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: |: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: head: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: 1: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: |: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: awk: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: =: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: {print $2}: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: |: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: awk: No such file or directory\n' +
      'grep: {print $1}: No such file or directory\n'
  ]
```

Please help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js world, try `process.env.ENV_VAR_NAME` instead of just `ENV_VAR_NAME`.